# Cambiar una ImageView dentro de un AlertDialog (Android Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

Saludos ultimamente e tratado de hacer un juego de dados en Kotlin que se muestre por medio de un AlertDialog, dento del AlertDialog se puede ver 2 botones y 3 dados los dados son ImageView, lo que trato de hacer es que al momento de que apriete el boton ***Roll*** dentro del Alertview me cambie la imagen del dado por el resultado que me da Random sin embargo la imagen queda estatica y no realiza cambio alguno.

### Codigo XML

En el siguiente codigo hago referencia a las imagenes de los lados del dado asi como de dos botones el "btnRoll" el cual tendria que hacer el respectivo cambio de los ImageView y el "btnOk" el cual solo cerraria el AlertDialog

---

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#2C2E30"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginVertical="30dp"
        >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dado1"
                android:background="@drawable/dado6_aq"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dado2"
                android:background="@drawable/dado1_aq"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dado3"
                android:background="@drawable/dado3_aq"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRoll"
        android:text="Roll"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOk"
        android:text="OK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        />


</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

### Codigo AlertDialog

Este codigo esta hecho dentro de un MainActivity.kt solo tiene un boton que es el que ejecuta el AlertDialog tengo una funcion que obtiene un numero random el cual como resultado me da la seleccion del drawable que contiene el lado del dado que corresponde al numero y un Toast con el numero random

---

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var dadoImg: ImageView? = null
var dadoImg2: ImageView? = null



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    btnDados.setOnClickListener {
        val dadosAlertDialog = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dado,null)
        val dadosBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(dadosAlertDialog)

        val dAlertDialog = dadosBuilder.show()

        dadosAlertDialog.btnOk.setOnClickListener{

            dAlertDialog.dismiss()

        }

        dadosAlertDialog.btnRoll.setOnClickListener{

            rolldice()

        }

        dadoImg = findViewById(R.id.dado)
        dadoImg2 = findViewById(R.id.dado2)


    }



    }


    private fun rolldice() {


        val numRandom = Random.nextInt(6) + 1
        val dadoLado = when (numRandom) {

            1 -> R.drawable.dado1_aq
            2 -> R.drawable.dado2_aq
            3 -> R.drawable.dado3_aq
            4 -> R.drawable.dado4_aq
            5 -> R.drawable.dado5_aq


            else -> R.drawable.dado6_aq
        }

        dadoImg?.setImageResource(dadoLado)

        if(numRandom == 6){

            Toast.makeText(this,"A caido 6 !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }else{

            Toast.makeText(this,"A caido $numRandom !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }


    }


}
```

### Imagen AlertDialog

---

[image: Dados]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me imagino que quieres cambiar las imagenes de los 3 dados, cada vez que hagas click en RollDice, por lo que debes crear las referencias de tu layout que cargas en tu AlertDialog:

```
private lateinit var dado1: ImageView
private lateinit var dado2: ImageView
private lateinit var dado3: ImageView


. . .

// Basta con inflarlo una vez
val dadosAlertDialog = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dado,null)

// Obten las referencia de su respectivo layout
dado1 = dadosAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.dado1)
dado2 = dadosAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.dado2)
dado3 = dadosAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.dado3)


btnDados.setOnClickListener {
        val dadosBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(dadosAlertDialog)

        val dAlertDialog = dadosBuilder.show()

        dadosAlertDialog.btnOk.setOnClickListener{
            dAlertDialog.dismiss()
        }

        dadosAlertDialog.btnRoll.setOnClickListener{
            rolldice()
        }
    }
}


private fun getRandomDice() : Int {

    val numRandom = Random.nextInt(6) + 1
    val dadoLado = when (numRandom) {

        1 -> R.drawable.dado1_aq
        2 -> R.drawable.dado2_aq
        3 -> R.drawable.dado3_aq
        4 -> R.drawable.dado4_aq
        5 -> R.drawable.dado5_aq
        else -> R.drawable.dado6_aq
    }
    // Esta validacion, la manejas como quieras. Puedes comparar directamente con el Id del dado
    if(numRandom == 6)
       Toast.makeText(this,"A caido 6 !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    else
       Toast.makeText(this,"A caido $numRandom !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    return dadoLado
}

private fun rolldice() {
        dado1.setImageResource(getRandomDice())
        dado2.setImageResource(getRandomDice())
        dado3.setImageResource(getRandomDice())
    }


}
```

Comment: Gracias algo asi estaba buscando

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar a enlazar el layout que contiene las imágenes en kotlin por la id, igual que tienes las imageView. Entonces utiliza el metodo layout.removeallviews. dentro del onClick del botón correspondiente. Justo debajo del remove actualiza la imageView con la imagen que quieras mostrar. Prueba así, si te siguen quedando dudas te lo puedo hacer en java que es muy parecido.

Un saludo, espero que te ayude!

Comment: Saludos Aridai y lamento la demora de mi respuesta, voy a intentar realizar el codigo en Kotlin estoy empezando a estudiar programacion por lo que no tengo mucha experiencia, te agradesco tu apoyo.